# In this Jest mock, why doesn't my implementation get used on the component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to test a React component with Jest. In the component, a module is required which is a factory function that returns an object of functions.

```
//tracker.js
export default () => {
  track: click => dosomething(click);
};

//component.js
import Tracker from './tracker';
const tracker = Tracker();

tracker.track();

//__tests__/component.test.js
import component from '../component';

describe('', () => {
  it('tracks the click', () => {
    const mockTrack = jest.fn();

    jest.mock('../tracker', () => () => ({
      track: mockTrack
    }));

    // do some testing...

    expect(mocktrackData).toHaveBeenCalledWith(constants.TRACKING);
  });
});
```

This would appear to work, however the tracker file that gets imported into the component is not my mock nor the original, but Jest's default mock based on the API of the original tracker file.

I have a few tests in the same file where I want to test different args being sent to the tracker.

Is this possible and what am I doing wrong here?

This is pseudo code, but close enough to convey intent.

Comment: `jest.mock` should be placed before component is imported

Comment: I am not importing the file I want to mock into the test file. Additionally, I want to change the mock for each test.

Comment: If you don't import, what are you testing ?

Comment: The file I am testing imports the file I want to mock as a dependency. I want to check that the mock has been called with certain args.

Comment: Then you have to `jest.mock` your module before importing the file you want to test. You can then mock each module method differently in your tests with `myMockedModule.myMethod.mockImplementation(() => {})`

Comment: Thanks for looking, but the issue is the module I want to mock is a factory and I can't mock the methods directly. I am trying to figure out how to mock the entire module "dynamically"

Comment: Isn't a factory just an other method you can mock ?

Answer (score 0):

Factory is just an other method you can mock :

```
// tracker.js
module.exports = () => ({
  track: () => {
    console.log('track implementation');
  }
});

// index.js
const Tracker = require('./tracker');

const index = () => {
  const tracker = Tracker();
  tracker.track();
};

module.exports = {
  index
};

// index.test.js
jest.mock('./tracker');

const { index } = require('./index');
const Tracker = require('./tracker');

it('should call mocked track', () => {
  const track = jest.fn(() => {
    console.log('track mock');
  });
  Tracker.mockImplementation(() => ({ track }));

  index();

  expect(track).toBeCalled();
});
```